# How do I get one of my Search Folders to display in Outlook Today?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm using a `Search Folder` called `For Follow Up` which lists my flagged emails in it, and I'd like to display it on the `Outlook Today` summary page.

Is there any way to do that?

On the `Outlook Today` screen, I click the `Customize...` button and then click the `Choose Folders` button the `Search Folder` is not listed on the `Select Folder` dialog.

I'm using Outlook from Office 365 Pro Plus with version 1902.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is done via registry updates.
Your search folder needs to have a name.

- Close Outlook
- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\Today\Folders`
- Right-click an empty space on the right and select *New > String*
- Name the new item with the next number in order (or `0`)
- Double-click the new item and give it the value
  `Search Folders\Your-Folder-Name`
- Now when you start Outlook it should show your Search folder in the
  Outlook Today page.